# How to get program to print, if a boolean variable is true?

Tags: java, if-statement, methods, boolean

I know this seems like a very simple question, but keep in mind I am new to java. Attached is my source code and at the end I write and if statement to print out "Password is valid" if the variable "valid" is true. The code runs fine until it hits this point, at which instead of printing "password is valid", it exits the program? I have looked at numerous thread on stack overflow to see how this could be solved and most threads suggest that this code should work. Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PasswordValidator {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //declare name and pass and insert scanner
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String name = "name";
    String pass = "pass";

    // tell user to type name and password and store  as variables
    System.out.print("Enter user name: ");
    name = sc.nextLine();
    check(name);  // check if name is equal to -1
    System.out.print("Enter password: ");
    pass = sc.nextLine();
    validate(name,pass); // call method 
}

static boolean validate(String userName, String password) {
    //declare necessary variables
    String upperCase = ".*[A-Z].*";
    String lowerCase = ".*[a-z].*";
    String number = ".*[0-9].*";
    String special = ".*[^A-Za-z0-9 ].*";
    boolean valid = true;

    if (password.matches("-1")) { // if input for password is -1 exit program
        System.exit(0);
    }
    if (password.matches(upperCase)) {  // check to see if input has one upper case letter  
        valid = true;
    }
        else  
            System.out.println("Password should contain at least one upper-case alphabet.");
            valid = false;
    if(password.matches(lowerCase)) {  // check to see if input has one lower case letter
        valid = true;
    }
        else 
            System.out.println("Password should contain at least one lower-case alphabet.");
            valid = false;  
    if (password.matches(number)) { // check to see if input has one number
        valid = true;
    }
        else
            System.out.println("Password should contain at least one number.");
            valid = false;      
    if(password.matches(special)) { // check to see if input has a special char.
        valid = true;
    }
        else
            System.out.println("Password should contain at least one special character.");
            valid = false;      
    if(password.length()>=7 && password.length() <= 10) { // make sure the password input = 7-10 char.
        valid = true;
    }
        else 
            System.out.println("Password should be within 7 to 10 characters in length.");  
            valid = false;  

    if (password.matches(".*\\s.*")) { // check to see if input has white spaces
        System.out.println("Password should not contain whitespace.");
        valid = false;
    }

    if(password.matches(userName))  { // give error if user name and password are the same
        System.out.println("Password should not contain or be the same as username.");
        valid = false;
    }
    // this is where I try to print if password is valid. for some reason my program just exits without printing :(
    if(valid==true) {
        System.out.print("Password is valid");
    }

    return valid;

}

// method used to check if user name is -1, and close program if so
static boolean check(String userName) {
    if (userName.matches("-1")){
            System.exit(0);
    }
    return true;

}
}
```

Comment: `if(validate(name,pass)) { // do what you want to do next }`

Comment: did you debug at that point and checked your value of valid as I think it will be false and that is why your code is exiting.

Comment: When you are  else
            System.out.println("Password should contain at least one special character.");
            valid = false; doing this, it will always change your valid varuiable to false, use curly braces in else clause.

Comment: All of your `else` clauses without `{` and `}`... they only cover **one** statement. You're setting `valid` to `false` ***many*** times. Also, you shouldn't set `valid` to `true` once it is `false`. You have some logic problems to overcome here.

Comment: see @ElliottFrisch comment

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is the braces after else. You print some statement in else and then the valid flag is made false regardless of the condition being true or false. Also, close the scanner at the end. Also, you don't need to check if valid==true, you can simply put it in the if condition. You code would look like

```
package com.digit.main;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class PasswordValidator {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // declare name and pass and insert scanner
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String name = "name";
    String pass = "pass";

    // tell user to type name and password and store as variables
    System.out.print("Enter user name: ");
    name = sc.nextLine();
    check(name); // check if name is equal to -1
    System.out.print("Enter password: ");
    pass = sc.nextLine();
    validate(name, pass); // call method
    sc.close();
}

static boolean validate(String userName, String password) {
    // declare necessary variables
    String upperCase = ".*[A-Z].*";
    String lowerCase = ".*[a-z].*";
    String number = ".*[0-9].*";
    String special = ".*[^A-Za-z0-9 ].*";
    boolean valid = true;

    if (password.matches("-1")) { // if input for password is -1 exit program
        System.exit(0);
    }
    if (password.matches(upperCase)) { // check to see if input has one upper case letter
        valid = true;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Password should contain at least one upper-case alphabet.");
        valid = false;
    }
    if (password.matches(lowerCase)) { // check to see if input has one lower case letter
        valid = true;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Password should contain at least one lower-case alphabet.");
        valid = false;
    }
    if (password.matches(number)) { // check to see if input has one number
        valid = true;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Password should contain at least one number.");
        valid = false;
    }
    if (password.matches(special)) { // check to see if input has a special char.
        valid = true;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Password should contain at least one special character.");
        valid = false;
    }
    if (password.length() >= 7 && password.length() <= 10) { // make sure the password input = 7-10 char.
        valid = true;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Password should be within 7 to 10 characters in length.");
        valid = false;
    }

    if (password.matches(".*\\s.*")) { // check to see if input has white spaces
        System.out.println("Password should not contain whitespace.");
        valid = false;
    }

    if (password.matches(userName)) { // give error if user name and password are the same
        System.out.println("Password should not contain or be the same as username.");
        valid = false;
    }
    // this is where I try to print if password is valid. for some reason my program
    // just exits without printing :(
    if (valid) {
        System.out.print("Password is valid");
    }

    return valid;

}

// method used to check if user name is -1, and close program if so
static boolean check(String userName) {
    if (userName.matches("-1")) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
    return true;

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Your `else` clauses do not include braces and thus you blindly set `valid` to `false` many many times. Also, you don't want to set `valid` back to `true` once it has failed a test. Fixing both of those issues should give you something like,

```
static boolean validate(String userName, String password) {
    // declare necessary variables
    String upperCase = ".*[A-Z].*";
    String lowerCase = ".*[a-z].*";
    String number = ".*[0-9].*";
    String special = ".*[^A-Za-z0-9 ].*";
    boolean valid = true;

    if (password.equals("-1")) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
    if (!password.matches(upperCase)) { // check to see if input has one upper case letter
        System.out.println("Password should contain at least one upper-case alphabet.");
        valid = false;
    }
    if (!password.matches(lowerCase)) { // check to see if input has one lower case letter
        System.out.println("Password should contain at least one lower-case alphabet.");
        valid = false;
    }
    if (!password.matches(number)) { // check to see if input has one number
        System.out.println("Password should contain at least one number.");
        valid = false;
    }
    if (!password.matches(special)) { // check to see if input has a special char.
        System.out.println("Password should contain at least one special character.");
        valid = false;
    }
    if (password.length() < 7 || password.length() > 10) { // make sure the password input = 7-10 char.
        System.out.println("Password should be within 7 to 10 characters in length.");
        valid = false;
    }
    if (password.matches(".*\\s.*")) { // check to see if input has white spaces
        System.out.println("Password should not contain whitespace.");
        valid = false;
    }
    if (password.matches(userName)) { // give error if user name and password are the same
        System.out.println("Password should not contain or be the same as username.");
        valid = false;
    }
    if (valid) {
        System.out.println("Password is valid");
    }

    return valid;
}
```

Comment: I had a feeling it was a simple mistake that I was making. putting the braces around the else did the trick. It runs fine now even with changing the value of valid so many time. I guess I don't understand why its a problem to change valid from true to false multiple time.

Comment: @Cole an all lowercase password should not be valid. Your code will display a message, set valid to false (no uppercase letters), then determine there are lowercase letters so the password is valid again.

Answer (score 0):

You should put your all `else` parts like this with brackets,

ex:

Instead of using this

```
else 
    System.out.println("Password should be within 7 to 10 characters in length.");  
    valid = false;
```

Please use it like this

```
else
{
  System.out.println("Password should be within 7 to 10 characters in length.");
  valid = false;
}
```

You should do this to all your `else` parts and it should work.

If you use else without brackets only the first line that comes after `else` will be inside `else`. Thats the error you do here. Also you can improve your code by removing unnecessary assigns to false and true always if you take a good look at how it will execute